# amscls and ams fonts with TexLive, installing fonts

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I'm getting the following error:

[debian:doc]$ latex amsbook-template.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./amsbook-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
...
Contents
(./amsbook-template.toc) [5]

! LaTeX Error: File `.tex' not found.

In specifics, it appears on mds font, which is in the directory tree:

aTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 64.
 (/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 64.

(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1

] [4{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Contents
(./amsbook-template.toc)
\tf@toc=\write4
\openout4 = `amsbook-template.toc'.

[5

]

! LaTeX Error: File `.tex' not found.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably better to get an up to date latex system instead. Remember texlive includes almost everything from ctan. But the Debian version of texlive is split up into a plethora of Debian packages. Though since the amsmath system is such a core part of latex, I wonder why you don't have amsfont already. And it should be available as a Debian package already. Nowadays only very few latex packages need to be installed by hand

Comment: amsfonts have been part of texlive since the start, you should never have to get that zip file and unpack them manually. just install it using the package manager (if you are sure they are not already installed, which would be surprising)

Comment: I have all the fonts installed, texlive-full, therefore I'm wondering if it is something with amscls and newer Tex distro.  I had to change /include to /input to get compilation working at all.  Does anyone else have this working on Debian 9?

Comment: Please do not edit the space reserved for **questions** with an answer! You can **answer** your own question -- then your answer is placed in the space here reserved only for answers and please delete then the "solution" in your question :-) Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

For those encountering this error.

1. in amsbook-template.tex : change /include to /input
2. comment out any input statement that do not include files with %
3. Tex-Live full installation should have all you need to compile

Thanks